# What should be given as an input to linkage function - tfidf matrix or similarity between different elements of tfidf matrixes?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, cosine-similarity

I have the following python notebook which aims to cluster different groups of abstracts based on the similarity between their text.
I have two approaches here: one to use tfidf numpy array of documents as it is in the linkage function and second is to find the similarity between the tfidf array of different documents and then to use that similarity matrix for clustering. I am unable to understand which one is correct.

#### Approach 1:

I used cosine_similarity to find out the similarity matrix *(cosine)* of tfidf matrix. I first converted the redundant matrix *(cosine)* into the condensed distance matrix *(distance_matrix)* using squareform function. Then distance_matrix is fed into linkage function and using Dendograms I have plotted the graph.

#### Approach 2:

I used the condensed form of tfidf numpy array into the linkage function and plotted the dendograms.

My question is what is correct? According to the data as far as i can understand, the approach 2 seems to be correct, but to me approach 1 makes sense. It would be great if someone can explain me what is right here in this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Let me know if anything remains unclear in the question.

```
import pandas, numpy
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

###Data Cleaning

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
df=pandas.read_csv('WIPO_CSV.csv')


import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')


documents_no_stopwords=[]

def preprocessing(word):
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(word)

    processed_words = []
    for w in tokens:
        if w in stop_words:
            continue
        else:
            processed_words.append(w)

***This step creates a list of text documents with only the nouns in    them***
    documents_no_stopwords.append(' '.join(processed_words))

for text in df['TEXT'].tolist():
    preprocessing(text)

***Converting into tfidf form***
*Latin is used as utf8 decoder was facing some trouble with the text.*

vectoriser = TfidfVectorizer(encoding='latin1')

***we have numpy here which is in normalised form***

tfidf_documents = vectoriser.fit_transform(documents_no_stopwords)


##Cosine Similarity as the input to linkage should be a distance vector

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

cosine = cosine_similarity(tfidf_documents)
distance_matrix = squareform(cosine,force='tovector',checks=False)

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage

##Linkage based on tfidf of each document
z_num=linkage(tfidf_documents.todense(),'ward')

z_num  #tfidf

array([[11.        , 12.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ],
   [18.        , 19.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ],
   [20.        , 31.        ,  0.        ,  3.        ],
   [21.        , 32.        ,  0.        ,  4.        ],
   [22.        , 33.        ,  0.        ,  5.        ],
   [17.        , 34.        ,  0.38208619,  6.        ],
   [15.        , 28.        ,  1.19375843,  2.        ],
   [ 6.        ,  9.        ,  1.24241258,  2.        ],
   [ 7.        ,  8.        ,  1.27069483,  2.        ],
   [13.        , 37.        ,  1.28868301,  3.        ],
   [ 4.        , 24.        ,  1.30850122,  2.        ],
   [36.        , 39.        ,  1.32090275,  5.        ],
   [10.        , 16.        ,  1.32602346,  2.        ],
   [27.        , 38.        ,  1.32934025,  3.        ],
   [23.        , 25.        ,  1.32987072,  2.        ],
   [ 3.        , 29.        ,  1.35143582,  2.        ],
   [ 5.        , 14.        ,  1.35401753,  2.        ],
   [26.        , 42.        ,  1.35994878,  3.        ],
   [ 2.        , 45.        ,  1.40055438,  3.        ],
   [ 0.        , 40.        ,  1.40811825,  3.        ],
   [ 1.        , 46.        ,  1.41383622,  3.        ],
   [44.        , 50.        ,  1.4379821 ,  5.        ],
   [41.        , 43.        ,  1.44575227,  8.        ],
   [48.        , 51.        ,  1.45876241,  8.        ],
   [49.        , 53.        ,  1.47130328, 11.        ],
   [47.        , 52.        ,  1.49944936, 11.        ],
   [54.        , 55.        ,  1.69814818, 22.        ],
   [30.        , 56.        ,  1.91299937, 24.        ],
   [35.        , 57.        ,  3.1967033 , 30.        ]])

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
dn = dendrogram(z_num)
plt.show()
```

### Linkage based on similarity

```
z_sim=linkage(distance_matrix,'ward')
z_sim  *Cosine Similarity*

array([[0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
   [2.00000000e+00, 3.00000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 3.00000000e+00],
   [1.70000000e+01, 3.10000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 4.00000000e+00],
   [3.00000000e+00, 4.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
   [1.00000000e+01, 3.30000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 3.00000000e+00],
   [5.00000000e+00, 7.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
   [6.00000000e+00, 1.80000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
   [1.10000000e+01, 1.90000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
   [1.20000000e+01, 2.00000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
   [8.00000000e+00, 2.40000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
   [1.60000000e+01, 2.10000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
   [2.20000000e+01, 2.70000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
   [9.00000000e+00, 2.90000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
   [2.60000000e+01, 4.20000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 3.00000000e+00],
   [1.40000000e+01, 3.40000000e+01, 3.97089886e-03, 4.00000000e+00],
   [2.30000000e+01, 4.40000000e+01, 1.81733052e-02, 5.00000000e+00],
   [3.20000000e+01, 3.50000000e+01, 2.14592323e-02, 6.00000000e+00],
   [2.50000000e+01, 4.00000000e+01, 2.84944415e-02, 3.00000000e+00],
   [1.30000000e+01, 4.70000000e+01, 5.02045376e-02, 4.00000000e+00],
   [4.10000000e+01, 4.30000000e+01, 5.10902795e-02, 5.00000000e+00],
   [3.70000000e+01, 4.50000000e+01, 5.40176402e-02, 7.00000000e+00],
   [3.80000000e+01, 3.90000000e+01, 6.15118462e-02, 4.00000000e+00],
   [1.50000000e+01, 4.60000000e+01, 7.54874869e-02, 7.00000000e+00],
   [2.80000000e+01, 5.00000000e+01, 9.55487454e-02, 8.00000000e+00],
   [5.20000000e+01, 5.30000000e+01, 3.86911095e-01, 1.50000000e+01],
   [4.90000000e+01, 5.40000000e+01, 4.16693529e-01, 2.00000000e+01],
   [4.80000000e+01, 5.50000000e+01, 4.58764920e-01, 2.40000000e+01],
   [3.60000000e+01, 5.60000000e+01, 5.23422380e-01, 2.60000000e+01],
   [5.10000000e+01, 5.70000000e+01, 5.49419077e-01, 3.00000000e+01]])

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(25, 10))
dn = dendrogram(z_sim)
plt.show()
```

accuracy for clustering of data is compared with this photo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EgkPqwh7AKhGqOe1zf9KNjSMxPQ9Xfd9/view?usp=sharing

The dendogram that I got are available in the following notebook link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TB7aFK4lPDo43GY74FPOqVOx1AxWV-A_/view?usp=sharing
open this html using internet browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scipy only supports *distances* for HAC, not similarities.

Then the results should be the same. So there is no "right" or "wrong".

At some point you need the distance matrix in linearized form. It is probably most efficient to use a) a method that can process *sparse* data (avoiding any `todense` call), and b) directly produces the linearize form, rather than generating the entire matrix and then dropping half of it.

Comment: So if i want to cluster based on similarities, is there any algorithm for that or should I write my own method by modifying the existing methods in HAC?

Comment: Well, for example Ward *requires* squared Euclidean. So with cosine, `1-cos` is the proper way. With other similarities you'll need to do the math first. With single, complete, average it is fairly easy to see that `max-sim` will work.

Comment: But the implementation assumed you want to merge the *smallest* (distance) and not the largest value. If you want to maximize similarities, you'll need to rewrite much of the code.

Comment: Also when we say, that we need the distance matrix in linearized form, it means that if the method returns a 2d matrix with first row containing document 1 being compared to every other document, followed by each row with 2 comparison less (one with the previous document and the other with itself). Would this modification make sense?

Comment: Here is another approach that i am thinking of. What if instead of finding the similarity between the documents, i find a relative similarity of each document with respect to say, a numpy array of ones(numpy.ones). Now, i will have a vector of each document being compared to a common vector which is populated with one only. For clustering, the indices of the vector with approximately equal value, will be clustered together. Do you think, this would work?

Comment: See the scipy API for ways to compute the linearized distance matrix directly. And no, it won't work to reduce everything to a single distance. Consider earth, and you map everything to just the distance from the North Pole. Then Canada = Russia? But there are some methods that take this idea a step further, just keep on studying literature.

Comment: thanks for your input. The north pole example was fabulous in order to explain the mistake i was making. I will look in detail at the concepts.